# How to update PrimaryKeyRelatedField field of a nested relation? / Allow to GET a full object but POST/PUT/PATCH with only an id on related fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

In the serializer, `country` is the object of Country Model, and I have added a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` with ending `*_id` to get the id and use it to send from the front-end if there is any change.

The Address Serializer:

```py
class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    country = CountrySerializer(read_only = True)
    country_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset = Country.objects.all(), source="country") #field added to get the id

    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = '__all__'
```

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = CategorySerializer(read_only=True)
    category_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset = Category.objects.all(), source='category', allow_null=True)
    addresses = AddressSerializer(many=True, read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = '__all__'

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        addresses = validated_data.pop('addresses')
        instance = super().update(instance, validated_data)

        address_list = []
        for address in addresses:
            address_id = address['id']
            if address_id != 0:
                address_instance = Address.objects.get(id = address_id)
                address_instance.country_id = address['country_id']
                address_instance.save()
            elif address_id == 0:
                address.pop('id', None)
                
        address_list.append(Address.objects.create(**address))
           instance.addresses.add(*address_list)
           return instance
```

JSON Request TO UPDATE Company and addresses

```
{
   "id":25,
   "category_id":1,
   "name":"COMPANY SA DE CV",
   "addresses":[{
         "id":1,
         "country_id":2,
         "content_type":36,
         "object_id":25 
   }]
}
```

My problem is that, if I send (PATCH or PUT) in the request `country_id` or the others `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`, I receive the ERROR, since they don't appear in `validated_data`.
I have tried with `read_only=False`, `write_only=True` in this field.

```
    ...
    File "/Users/obedramales/Sites/webegin-project/webegin/app/serializers.py", line 214, in update
    address_instance.country_id = address['country_id']
KeyError: 'country_id'
```

This is when it was updated from the company, but if I update just the address directly it does fine.

I would like to know what is the correct way to handle this please?

The models are defined like these:

```
class Company(SafeDeleteModel):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    addresses = GenericRelation('Address')
```

In this model I have a generic relationship from Address to Company. A company can have many addresses.

```
class Address(SafeDeleteModel):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name='model_addresses', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried changing the following line of code

```
address_instance.country_id = address['country_id']
```

to

```
address_instance.country = address['country']
```

and it works, When I send `country_id` updates the correct id, but it is necessary to have `country_id` declared

```
country = CountrySerializer(read_only = True)
country_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source="country", queryset = Country.objects.all())
```

in JSON Request

```
...
"country_id": 3,
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the `country_id` field in the `AddressSerializer`.

```
class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    country = CountrySerializer(read_only = True)
    country_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset = Country.objects.all(), source="country") #field added to get the id

    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_fields = ['country_id']
```

The `country_id` field is not defined in the `Address` class. So you need to set that field additionally.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that I can't access  `address['country_id']` because it does not appear in `validated_data `

Comment: Hey, I changed the answer. Please check it again.

Comment: Thanks, I tried with `extra_fields` but i get the same error.
I tried changing `address_instance.country = address['country']` and it works, but I don't know if it's a good practice since country is an object `country: {id: 1, code: "MEX", name: "Mexico"}`, and besides that way if it takes the `country_id`, I change only `country_id` and so I send it and that variable is the one that takes into account and not `country`, since `country` is not changed in the front-end
 it's very strange hahaha